# How to use itemCount in SliverGrid?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid

Most probably I got the concept my SliverGrid entirely wrong,

What I am trying to do is, UI wise I want the collapsible SliverAppBar which is already available in Flutter. My main content body is set of images coming from API response and already parsed and loaded to a List variable.

Now here is my code:

```
body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 150.0, backgroundColor: Colors.green),
            SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index){
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 2.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(fit: BoxFit.cover,image: myimagelist[index].thumbnail, placeholder:kTransparentImage,fadeInCurve: Curves.bounceIn,),
                    ),
                  )
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I think this is probably because I can't tell the widget that how long is my data. For GridView.builder `itemCount` parameter is there, but SliverGrid doesn't have such an option. What do here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SliverGrid widget doesn't have a property named `itemCount`. However, if you read the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverChildBuilderDelegate/SliverChildBuilderDelegate.html), you'll see that it's delegate property which takes a SliverChildBuilderDelegate has a property called `childCount`. You can use this property to set the number of childrens you want in your slivergrid.

```
delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index){
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 2.0),
    child: InkWell(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 8.0,
        child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(fit: BoxFit.cover,image: myimagelist[index].thumbnail, placeholder:kTransparentImage,fadeInCurve: Curves.bounceIn,),
         ),
      )
    );
  },
  childCount: 3, // Your desired amount of children here 
),
```